# How to animate 5 dots on a screen linked to an algorithm

Tags: c#, wpf, algorithm, xaml

This is a screen shot of how it needs to look like.

[image: screenshot]

Hi guys, I am trying to make a WPF window. In it there are 5 dots. Each of the dots appear or disappear depending on an algorithm behind the scenes. I am wondering if someone can give me tips on how to achieve this.

I know I need to databind the dots to the algorithm but how exactly should I go about doing it? I am new to C#, XAML, WPF. I have created the dots in XAML using window resources and displaying it in the window. I need to know how to write the C# behind to link it such that it appears and disappears.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to control them individually, you could have 5 Boolean properties in your view model / code behind, like

public bool IsDot1Visible { 
      // implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged` depends on your framework
      get; set;
   }

You could set or unset these properties depending on your algorithm. To hide the dots or make them visible, create a simple style with triggers.

```
    <Style x:Key="MyDotStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Ellipse}">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsDot1Visible}" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

A little example with 5 independant booleans :

I used borders for dots but you can choose `Ellipse`.Colors are animated using `ColorAnimation`.

**Xaml :**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="Border" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"></Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Tag,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
                       <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation To="Red" 
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                                FillBehavior="HoldEnd" 
                                Duration="0:0:1"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation To="Blue" 
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                                FillBehavior="HoldEnd" 
                                Duration="0:0:1"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Border Width="10" Height="10" Tag="{Binding Point1Blue}" Style="{StaticResource Border}" CornerRadius="10"></Border>
        <Border Width="10" Height="10" Tag="{Binding Point2Blue}" Style="{StaticResource Border}"  CornerRadius="10"></Border>
        <Border Width="10" Height="10" Tag="{Binding Point3Blue}" Style="{StaticResource Border}"  CornerRadius="10"></Border>
        <Border Width="10" Height="10" Tag="{Binding Point4Blue}" Style="{StaticResource Border}"  CornerRadius="10"></Border>
        <Border Width="10" Height="10" Tag="{Binding Point5Blue}" Style="{StaticResource Border}"  CornerRadius="10"></Border>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**Model Context.cs :**

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class Context : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool _point1Blue;
        private bool _point2Blue;
        private bool _point3Blue;
        private bool _point4Blue;
        private bool _point5Blue;

        public Context()
        {
            Point1Blue = true;
            Point2Blue = true;
            Point3Blue = false;
            Point4Blue = true;
            Point5Blue = false;

        }

        public bool Point1Blue
        {
            get { return _point1Blue; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _point1Blue) return;
                _point1Blue = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Point1Blue");
            }
        }

        public bool Point2Blue
        {
            get { return _point2Blue; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _point2Blue) return;
                _point2Blue = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Point2Blue");
            }
        }

        public bool Point3Blue
        {
            get { return _point3Blue; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _point3Blue) return;
                _point3Blue = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Point3Blue");
            }
        }

        public bool Point4Blue
        {
            get { return _point4Blue; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _point4Blue) return;
                _point4Blue = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Point4Blue");
            }
        }

        public bool Point5Blue
        {
            get { return _point5Blue; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _point5Blue) return;
                _point5Blue = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Point5Blue");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

And the result :

[image]

Now you ll be able to change your UI by changing your 5 boolean values with the algorithm you want.

Answer (score 1):

Create an enum based on the states which will imply what needs to be shown and bind to that state. Then have  conversion constructor which will take in a parameter identifying the specific state which will turn on/off the ellipses

**Enum**

```
public enum States
{
    RedState,
    GreenState,
    OrangeState
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
        public States CurrentState
        {
            get { return _CurrentState; }
            set
            {
                _CurrentState = value;
                PropertyChanged("CurrentState");
            }
     }
```

**XAML**

```
<Window.Resources>
   <converters:OperationStateToVisiblity x:Key="StateToVisiblity" />
</Window.Resources>
    ...
<Ellipse Fill="DarkRed" Visibility="{Binding CurrentState, ConverterParameter=RedState, Converter={StaticResource StateToVisiblityReverse}}"/>
<Ellipse Fill="Green" Visibility="{Binding CurrentState, ConverterParameter=GreenState, Converter={StaticResource StateToVisiblityReverse}}" />
```

**Converter**

```
/// <summary>
/// Take the current state, passed in as value which is bound, and check it against
/// the parameter passed in. If the names match, the ellipse should be visible,
/// if not equal, then it should be collapsed.
/// </summary>
public class OperationStateToVisiblity : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (value != null)     && 
                (parameter != null) &&
                value.ToString().Equals(parameter.ToString())
            ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```